# Find the stationary points of $\nabla g(x,y) =log(y^2+4x^2-4)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the function $$g(x,y) =log(y^2+4x^2-4)$$ that I'm trying to find the stationary points on. I have first found $g_x$ and $g_y$

$$g_x = \frac{8x}{y^2+4x^2-4}$$
and
$$g_y = \frac{2y}{y^2+4x^2-4}$$

and I have let them both equal 0

$$g_x=0$$
$$\implies x=0$$
and hence,
$$y = 0$$

Which then shows the stationary point is at (0,0) which isn't in the domain of this particular function. 
Though I'm not sure if this is correct, or if I'm on the right track, could you please just check over my work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks correct.

The domain of g is:

$D: { (x,y): 4x^2+y^2 > 4}$

Which is an ellipse. $(0,0)$ is not in the domain as you found, thus g has no stationary points.

Comment: exactly what I had, thank you very much